# expect or expect "to" in this sentence?

Tags: complementation, catenative-verbs

> I *expect* question and debate those ideas which interest me.

Is it expect "to" or just "expect"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The proper form is

> I expect **to** question and debate those ideas which interest me.

It's clear from the context that **question** and **debate** are verbs. Hence, the verb **expect** is followed by other verbs. When a verb is followed by another verb, it's called a *[catenative verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenative_verb)*.

Most catenative verbs are followed either by a to-infinitive or a gerund-participial. Sometimes a verb can be followed by either, with no major difference in meaning:

> It began **to rain**.
>   It began **raining**.

For other verbs and contexts, there might be a difference in meaning.

Finally, there are some verbs that can be followed by a bare infinitive, but **expect** does not belong to their number. The most common example is **help**:

> I helped pack her bags.
>   I helped question and debate those ideas which interested me.